# change the back ground color of segmented control buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, uicolor

friends,

I am able to change the size of segments in segmented control but i need to change the background color of the segments to orange color

any detailed view will be helpful

Comment: See [here](http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/) to customise UISegmentControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the segment control tintColor (color code as per your required).

```
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.1 blue:.1 alpha:1];
```

Comment: is there any possibilities to change the particular segment color to white while it was selected!!

Comment: i tried above but it crashes  NSCFConstantString setTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a24
 uicolor is not recognized i think in this!! and is there any possibility for change style i tried     mySegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle =[UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled]; i think the coding type is wrong kindly guide me

Comment: i have tried -(void)setSelectedSegmentColor:(UISegmentedControl *)paramsender
{
    for (int i=0; i<[mySegmentedControl.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
        {
            [[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
        else
        {
            [[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    }
}
 but still it is not working please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Yes...! I have found a developers analysis, which can change the particular segment color. The codes are as follows:

```
(void)setSelectedSegmentColor:(UISegmentedControl *)mySegmentedControl{
    for (int i=0; i<[mySegmentedControl.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
        {
            [[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor: [UIColor greenColor]];
        }else{
            [[mySegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, please visit this link- http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/customize-or-change-color-of-selected-segment-in-uisegmentedcontrol/

I hope, this information will fulfill your need...!

Comment: yep i tried the above code but it shows warning local declaration of mysegmented control hides instance variable and doesnt works kindlly guide me

Comment: Well,,, In this case, i have found another example of codes from a blog. please refer these codes, written below:

      //set the view background to white
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Please let me know if this information is helful to you @gopinath

for further information, please follow this link- http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/01/ios-create-uisegmentedcontrol.html